# Why do I have duplicated items in GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

Im getting the first 9 items at first of the page and only after those 9, im getting the all 16 items that suppose to appear in the list.
How can I move these 9 duplicate items?

**That's my java code (SearchCategories.java)**

```
package com.example.zygy1;

public class SearchCategories extends MenuActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_categories);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
     //DON'T continue if the adapter is not empty; prevents duplicates
          gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                    openSearchResults(position);
        }


});

}
public void openSearchResults(int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResults.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
    // retrieve String drawable array
    TypedArray imgs=null;
     imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, getHeadline(i)));
    }

    return imageItems;

}
public String getHeadline(int num){
    String headline;
    if(num==0){ headline="כלי עבודה";}
    else if(num==1){ headline="מכשירי חשמל";}
    else if(num==2){ headline="לגינה";}
    else if(num==3){ headline="ספורט";}
    else if(num==4){ headline="מחשבים ומובייל";}
    else if(num==5){ headline="לתינוק ולילד";}
    else if(num==6){ headline="צילום";}
    else if(num==7){ headline="מסיבות ואירועים";}
    else if(num==8){ headline="ביגוד ואביזרים";}
    else if(num==9){ headline="מכשור וציוד אוכל";}
    else if(num==10){ headline="ריהוט";}
    else if(num==11){ headline="למטייל";}
    else if(num==12){ headline="רפואה";}
    else if(num==13){ headline="כלי נגינה";}
    else if(num==14){ headline="משחקים";}
    else { headline="אחר";}
    return headline;
}

public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;

        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = (ImageItem) data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }



}
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**And here the xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zygy1.SearchCategories" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
```

**Here is the xml of each item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

String array from String, By the way i work on eclipse

```
<string-array name="image_ids">
    <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_11</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_12</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_13</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_14</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_15</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_16</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Didnt see nothing wrong with your code. The problem is most likely in the array. Could you post the xml?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, all the xml files is in here..

Comment: hey so basically all the xml ia related to the views and the problem is in the dataset. post image_ids array. The problem is most likely there

Comment: Hey i posted my string array, because i realy dont find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array has 25 items in it... Goes from 1 to 9 then starts at 1 again.